# htacces and mod rewrite with second parameter and existing folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I believe this was answered many times, but i'm just unable to find the answer.

I'm trying to get friendly urls to work, but can't write the rewrite rules.

I need to rewrite **www.mysite.com/123** to **www.mysite.com/index.php?page=123**

and also a page like: **www.mysite.com/123/abc** to **www.mysite.com/index.php?page=123&secondParam=abc**

Also i want to be able to link to a page like: www.mysite.com/something/index.php via www.mysite.com/something and dont rewrite it to www.mysite.com/index.php?page=something if the folder something exists on the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
Lines starting with '#' are comments and are just to document the commands.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# calls to initiate our requests Apache's Rewrite Module (you need this only once)
RewriteEngine on

# "If the requests does not point to an existing file"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# "If the requests does not point to an existing folder"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# "If the request contains a "2 subfolders" structure, redirects it silently to ..."
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&secondParam=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Try this version of the last line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&secondParam=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&secondParam=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: that gives me an Internal Server Error

Comment: are u sure mod_rewrite is available? Remove the lines, leaving only RewriteEngine on, save and refresh.

Comment: i am sure. this works:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1

Comment: so: try removing each line, starting from the bottom, until you don't have the internal server error. Report which line causes issue.

Comment: commented out the last Rewrite Rule just before </IfModule>. The internal server error is gone, but now when i try www.mysite.com/1234, i get a 404 error.

Comment: make sure there is no space in the target url, i'll correct it in the Answer right away.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40900/discussion-between-pixeline-and-dusan)

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&secondParam=$2 [NC,QSA,L]` worked for me.